# Pointer error in assembly bubble sort

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

In my procedure of my bubble sort, I get this error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00000006 in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation.

This occurs at `ret` of the procedure. I am not sure what does error means or how to fix this.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
     arrayDW SDWORD 5,6,7,3,5,3    ;array

.code
     main PROC
          mov esi, OFFSET arrayDW       ;ESI points arrayDW
          mov ecx, LENGTHOF arrayDW     ;ECX = array count
          call Bubblesort               ;sorts arrayDW
         exit
     main ENDP


     Bubblesort PROC 

          push esi      ;save esi
          push ecx      ;save ecx 
          dec ecx       ; size of array

          L1:
               push ecx                 ;save outer loop count
               mov esi, arrayDW         ;point to first value in the array was {mov esi, arrayDW}

          L2:
               mov eax, arrayDW[esi]       ; get array value, eax is the comparer
               cmp arrayDW[esi+4], eax     ; compare current value with the next value
               jg L3               ; if [ESI=eax] <= [ESI+4], do not exchange
               xchg eax, arrayDW[esi+4]   ; exchange the pair since [ESI=eax] > [ESI+4]
               mov arrayDW[esi], eax       ; place the higher value 

          L3:
               add esi, 4        ;move both pointers foward
               loop L2           ; looping inner loop

               pop ecx           ;retrieve outer loop count
               loop L1           ; else repeat outer loop

               ret
    Bubblesort ENDP



END main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assembly is atrociously rusty, but it looks like you `push esi` and `push ecx` at the start of your bubblesort routine and never `pop` them, so your `ret` instruction would be trying to pull the caller's address off the stack and end up jumping to what had been `ecx`, that is, the length of your array. Your array had 6 elements in it, so it would make sense that you'd end up jumping to `0x00000006`.

You can fix this either by adding two `pop` instructions at the end of your subroutine or by removing the `push esi` and `push ecx` at the start of it.